# How to update a doc value from an iron-router function

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I know this is a nood question, but I'm trying to work out how to update a value in a document from a route in iron router. I've found the spot I need to put the function, but I'm struggling with the mongo code needed to make it work.

I'm trying to increment a views element each time a link is clicked, so have added the following code to the route.

```
   data: function () {
      var project = projectDocs.findOne(this.params._id);
      // need to increment views value by one
      console.log(project.views);
      projectDocs.update({id: project.id},
        {$inc: {views: 1}}
      );
      console.log(project.views);
      return project;
    }

  });
```

The project.views value is returning the correct value, but the code to update the value throws an exception at the moment.

I tried the simple thing of project.views++ which increments the variable within the function but it never gets pushed to the database (no surprises there I guess).

Can someone point me in the direction I need to get this value to inc (and is this even the right place to do this?).

Thanks.

Peter.

OK, I found this link that has lead me part of the way [http://books.google.com.au/books?id=uGUKiNkKRJ0C&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=Cannot+apply+$inc+modifier+to+non-number&source=bl&ots=h7qyOddRsf&sig=EWFw9kNLGHoFEUS-nTNsBStDRcQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cRGXUse0DNGciAfk6YHgCA&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=Cannot%20apply%20%24inc%20modifier%20to%20non-number&f=false](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=uGUKiNkKRJ0C&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=Cannot%20apply%20%24inc%20modifier%20to%20non-number&source=bl&ots=h7qyOddRsf&sig=EWFw9kNLGHoFEUS-nTNsBStDRcQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cRGXUse0DNGciAfk6YHgCA&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=Cannot%20apply%20%24inc%20modifier%20to%20non-number&f=false) which explains that you can only inc numeric values (I had this as a string it seems.

Now the problem is that I seem to be in an endless loop.

The function now looks like

```
 this.route('projectPage', {
    path: '/projects/:_id',
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe('singleProject', this.params._id);
    },
    data: function () {
      var project = projectDocs.findOne(this.params._id);
      // need to increment views value by one
      console.log("Views", project.views);
      console.log("Project", project);
      projectDocs.update(project._id,
        {$inc: {views: 1}}
      );
      console.log(project.views);
      return project;
    }

  });
```

Why would this be looping?

Answer (score 0):

Use _id instead of id. So

```
      projectDocs.update({_id: project._id},
        {$inc: {views: 1}}
      );
```

If that's not it, perhaps you could update your answer with whatever exception you are getting.

Comment: OK, changed the code to match what you have here and the exception thrown in the console is
"Exception while simulating the effect of invoking '/projectDocs/update'
Error: Cannot apply $inc modifier to non-number
 

...r("Cannot apply $inc modifier to non-number");"

Followed by a whole bunch of code.

Comment: The views field must be a number is all the exception is saying. Fix that and the update should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the fantastic new documentation on iron-router a bit further and moved the $inc function to the unload hook and all seems to be good.

```
 this.route('projectPage', {
    path: '/projects/:_id',
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe('singleProject', this.params._id);
    },
    data: function () {
      return projectDocs.findOne(this.params._id);
    },
    unload: function() {
      var project = projectDocs.findOne(this.params._id);
      // need to increment views value by one
      projectDocs.update(project._id,
        {$inc: {views: 1}}
      );
    }
    // could possibly use layout: popup_layout? here
  });
```

Would love some confirmation that this is actually where I should be doing this (and it does seem a bit inefficient to be doing so many "findOne"'s) but its working for the moment.